# An Unfortunate State

Tags: riddle, word

> At first I cheat you
> and then I offend you.
> At the end I am unseen,
> and if you have me so is all else.

**What am I?**

Comment: Okay first question, how do you put a single line break in this HTML editor

Comment: Hi Amos, and welcome :) For a single line break, use two spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: Fixed it for you :-)

Comment: @AmosZoellner You might find [this link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to markdown help useful for future formatting...

Comment: Haha! @Stiv , I saw what you did there.. ;-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **CONCUSSION**

*At first I cheat you*

> To **CON** somebody means to *cheat* them.

*and then I offend you.*

> To **CUSS** at somebody might cause them *offence*.

*At the end I am unseen,*

> An **ION** is a particle too small to be *seen*.

*and if you have me so is all else.*

> If you have a **[concussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concussion)** then you may very well have lost consciousness, and so for a period you don't see anything at all (*all else is unseen*)! An 'unfortunate state' (as per the title) indeed...

Comment: Yep that's right!